# PHP syntax: constructing a class from a member variable

Tags: php, syntax

I am trying to make a class from a member variable like this:

```
<?
class A{
    private $to_construct = 'B'; 
    function make_class(){
        // code to make class goes here
    }

}

class B{
    function __construct(){
        echo 'class constructed';
    }
}

$myA = new A();
$myA->make_class();
?>
```

I tried using:

```
 $myClass = new $this->to_construct();
```

and

```
$myClass = new {$this->to_construct}();
```

but neither worked. I ended up having to do this:

```
$constructor = $this->to_construct;
$myClass = new $constructor();
```

It seems like there should be a way to do this without storing the class name in a local variable. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
 $myClass = new $this->to_construct;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking I needed to put the parenthesis to show it was a function. Is there still a way to do this without having to store the local class name if you need to pass parameters to the constructor?

Comment: It's not a function, though. I'm not sure how you would do what you need in PHP, either.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using PHP 4 or something? On 5.2.9 `$myClass = new $this->to_construct();` works perfectly.

In the end it's what you have to live with, with PHP. PHP syntax and semantics are VERY inconsistent. For example, an array access to the result of a call is a syntax error:

```
function foo() {
  return array("foo","bar");
}
echo $foo()[0];
```

Any other language could do that but PHP can't. Sometimes you simply need to store values into local variables.

Same is true for `func_get_args()` in older versions of PHP. If you wanted to pass it to a function, you needed to store it in a local var first.

Answer (score 0):

If I read well between the lines you are trying to do something like this. Right?

```
class createObject{
    function __construct($class){
        $this->$class=new $class;
    }

}

class B{
    function __construct(){
        echo 'class B constructed<br>';
    }
    function sayHi(){
        echo 'Hi I am class: '.get_class();
    }
}

class C{
    function __construct(){
        echo 'class C constructed<br>';
    }
    function sayHi(){
        echo 'Hi I am class: '.get_class();
    }
}
$wantedClass='B';
$finalObject = new createObject($wantedClass);
$finalObject->$wantedClass->sayHi();
```

--
Dam